# Drop-down list failing first validation

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

Environment is: VS 2019, EF, Core 2.2, and ASP.net MVC Web Application.

**The problem:** My drop-down list, or perhaps the input text-box bound to the model, gives a validation error on the first submit, but correctly submits on the second post.

**What I'm after:** I would like to have a short List of items that limit the users choice, upon list selection I want to bind that value to the model variable, not hard right? Well, I must be not understanding something.

**What I have so far:**

Controller Get Code:

```
    if (applicationUser == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    // Set Page Values
    ViewBag.Roles = RolesSelectList(applicationUser.RoleName);

    return View(applicationUser);
```

Helper Method to Populate Dropdown:

```
private List<SelectListItem> RolesSelectList(string selectedRole)
{
    var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    selectList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "None", Value = "None".ToString(), Selected = (selectedRole == "None") });
    selectList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Staff", Value = "Staff".ToString(),  Selected = (selectedRole == "Staff") });
    selectList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "User", Value = "User".ToString(), Selected = (selectedRole == "User") });
    return selectList;
}
```

Model Field Validate Attributes:

```
   [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Role Name must be Alphabectic greater than 4 characters")]
    [StringLength(5, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be between {2} and {1} characters.")]
    [Display(Name = "Role Name")]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
```

Page HTML(Relative Info):

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="RoleName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input id="tbxRoleName" asp-for="RoleName" class="form-control" style="width:0px;height:0px;margin:0;padding:0px;border:none;"/>
                @Html.DropDownList("RoleName", new SelectList(ViewBag.Roles as System.Collections.IList, "Text", "Value"),
                                new { @class = "form-control" })
                <span asp-validation-for="RoleName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

    <script>
        $('#RoleName').change(function () {
            $("#tbxRoleName").val($("#RoleName").val());
        });
    </script>
```

**Explanation of the HTML and Script:**
 I really only want the drop-down to bind to the model field, but for some reason I can not get the drop-down to show initial values or if and when I get the list to display the selected default value, it no longer changes the role in the database. So I ended up leaving the Input field bound to the model and using jquery to change the input's value to the drop-down list's value when it changes. The code shown works, but when I submit the form I get validation errors. If I hit submit again, the form is correctly submitted. I watched the post method, it does not seem to get hit until the second post.

I also tried setting the input's type to hidden, but when I did that, the form never would submit, hence the ugly styling.

Any help or insight you can give is appreciated.

Comment: Just an update, I have also tried:
 @Html.DropDownListFor(l=>l.RoleName, new SelectList(ViewBag.Roles, "Text", "Value"),
                                new { @class = "form-control" })
However this does not validate at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around, with one caveat.
My Controller Get Code:

```
    // Set Page Values
    ViewBag.RolesList = new SelectList(RolesSelectList(), "Value", "Text", applicationUser.RoleName);
```

Helper Method to Populate Dropdown:

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RolesSelectList()
{
    var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    selectList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "None",  Text = "None" });
    selectList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "Staff", Text = "Staff"});
    selectList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "User",  Text = "User" });
    return selectList;
}
```

Page HTML(Relative Info):

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DropDownList("UserRole", ViewBag.RolesList as SelectList,
        "-- Select Role --", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

And removed the JQuery:

The only caveat is that it made me remove the required attribute on the model field. If anyone has a suggestion that's great, otherwise I accept this as my answer.